# How to ORDER BY CALCULATED SUM with Another Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

For example, I have 2 table 'meta' and 'log'

in meta table:

```
| type | score |
|------|-------|
| a    | 1     |
| b    | 2     |
| c    | 3     |
```

in log table:

```
| log_id | log_type | object_id |
|--------|----------|-----------|
| 1      | a        | 13        | 
| 2      | b        | 13        |
| 3      | a        | 14        |
| 4      | c        | 14        |
| 5      | b        | 15        |
| 6      | c        | 15        |
```

so we know:

```
object 13 got score: a+b = 3
object 14 got score: a+c = 4
object 15 got score: b+c = 5
```

I want to query log table group by object id and order by sum of object score, is it possible?

Comment: going through some of my old answers. What happened here?

Answer (score 1):

```
select log.object_id, sum(meta.score)
from log
left join meta on meta.type = log.log_type
group by log.object_id
order by sum(meta.score) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

This will produced the desired output

```
SELECT object_id, sum(score) from log 
INNER JOIN meta on meta.type = log.log_type group by object_id ORDER BY sum(score);
```

But have you got the correct table design? You need to join on the meta.type and log.log_type column but this implies that if the `log_type` is 'a' the value of 3 is common for all `object_id`s is this really what you want?

Comment: yeah, the table design is what I want. In my project, the score of type is changeable by client, that's why I couldn't store score in log table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select object_id,sum(score) as c FROM `log` as a INNER JOIN `meta` as b on a.log_type=b.type group by object_id order by c desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT log.object_id, sum(score) total_score
FROM meta
INNER JOIN log on meta.type = log.log_type
GROUP BY log.object_id
```